# UIButton not appearing on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

Alright, I am testing around a bit with core data, something I recently have started to discover, basically, what i have so far, is a single view app, that has a data source, and i can press a button and it brings up and alert, which from there i can add names to the list, and delete names from the list, i can close my app and still maintain my data. here is the issue/question, i am trying to do an update, so i can edit names in the list, i have a uibutton set up on my prototype cell, and i have it linked to my viewController, and have a function set inside the IBAction for the button. however, the button does not appear in my sim at run time.

here i have some code.

this is code for the edit button, and its function:

```
@IBAction func editButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // 2
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Update",
                                  message: "Please enter the new name.",
                                  preferredStyle: .Alert)
    // 3
    let updateAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",
                                     style: .Default){(_) in
                                        let nameTextField = alert.textFields![0]
                                        self.updateName(indexPath.row, newName: nameTextField.text!)
                                        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // 4
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(nil)

    alert.addAction(updateAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    // 5
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath func

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!
    let people = peoples[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = people.name
    return cell
}
```

here is an image of my storyboard

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYA1i.png)

if you need further information or code, please let me know and i will provide it.

Comment: why do you have didSelectRowAtIndexPath method inside the button action..please make that outside the method

Comment: Seconding Anish, you definitely messed up the implementation of didSelectRowAtIndexPath. It absolutely does not go inside your IBAction. Also, it would be much more useful to us to see cellForRowAtIndexPath and your UITableViewCell xib / storyboard than this method. This has nothing to do with displaying the button.

Comment: @Dare , I am fairly new to this, so i was unaware, ill make that change. how would i go about doing that? i have updated the question to show my cellForRowAtIndexPath function, im not sure if thats what youre referring to. and ive provided a link to my storyboard image.

Comment: @anishparajuli if you could point me in a direction as to what i should do instead, i previously had it set instead of a button as just to detect when a cell was tapped on, but that wasnt working either.

Comment: Where do you register your custom cell and its reuse identifier with the table view?

Comment: @Dare i have this ' tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
' line of code in my viewDidLoad, is that what you're asking for?

Comment: @Dare i can give you a link to my git repo for it, if that would be at all beneficial

Comment: Well, that's your problem. UITableViewCell is a standard cell, not your subclass. Standard cells do not have buttons. You need to fix registerClass() and read up on the UITableView documentation.

Comment: @Dare are you saying I need a custom class for my table view cell? i will go do that, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Probably best to make a xib file and call .registerNib(nibName: bundle: forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)